# How to use MS Azure AppFabric via proxy server in corporate network

Tags: azure, service, appfabric, bus

I'm testing the Service Bus AppFabric within our corporate network by runnng the Echo service sample from the AppFabric SDK samples (WindowsAzurePlatformAppFabricSDKSamples_V1.0-CS). However, the code seems to hang at the host.Open(), and no exceptions being thrown.

I left the program running like hours but it's still hung at that line with no exceptions.

Does anyone have a hint about this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Have been struggling with this today as well. You can add the following in your config:

```
  <system.net>
    <defaultProxy useDefaultCredentials="true">
      <proxy proxyaddress="http://xyz:8080"  usesystemdefault="True"/>
      <module type="ServiceBusHost.CustomProxy, ServiceBusHost"/>
    </defaultProxy>
  </system.net>
```

Unfortunately this does not work in all cases.